# Azure Devops Insert new stage or re order pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

How can I insert a new stage at the start of my pipeline, or just re order existing.
When I click add it puts it below the 2nd stage and I can't figure out how to put it at the front.

NB this is not a release. This is a pipeline I am editing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated
[image: Stage2 I want at start]

I'd be happy if you just know how to edit the yaml file which I assume is behind this someplace. All i seem to have now is this visual interface

Comment: For info after JukkaK helpfully solved my issue MSoft came back to me with a link to the solution (which wasn't coming up on my google searches!) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/define-multistage-release-process?view=azure-devops#extend-a-release-pipeline-by-adding-stages

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With visual editor, edit the trigger of the stage (the lightning icon within the stage) and set the trigger to "After a release". The picture implicates that you now have the trigger set to "After Stage: Deploy to UAT", which usually is the case if you add/clone the stage from underneath that stage. Remove the "After the stage" trigger if needed.

Comment: As for yaml, you would currently have to be using multi-staged pipelines. With classic pipelines, you only have visual editor available for release pipelines.

Comment: Thank you so much, i knew it would be silly. Yep made new stage put after build then changed the uat to be after stage the new one and now all as desired